# Invalid command name ' ' when running bash script

Tags: bash

When running the following in a bash script:

```
python setup.py build_ext \ 
    --include-dirs=/root/deps/include:/root/deps/include/flint \
    --library-dirs=/root/deps/lib:/root/deps/lib/flint
```

I receive the following output:

```
invalid command name ' '
```

I am honestly at a loss to explain this output. I haven't seen it before and the command looks right. What could be causing it?

Comment: Tip: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) detects this and other common bash issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure those `\` characters are the *last* thing on the line - it looks like you may have a space following one or more of them.

For example, here's a transcript of me putting a space after the `\` in the first case but not in the second:

```
pax> python \ 
python: can't open file ' ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

pax> python \
...> nofile.py
python: can't open file 'nofile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Ignore the fact that they both generate the same type of error, I couldn't be bothered creating a Python script for the second case. The important things is the `\<space>` is *not* seen as a line continuation character so the line is considered complete.